# How to compile SwiftPackage executable product?

Tags: swift, github, homebrew, swift-package-manager

I have a Swift library that exports a CLI executable product. I want to ship the CLI binary as a Git release asset to ease the installation, but I am struggling to build the package.

```swift
let package = Package(
    name: "swift-graphql",
    platforms: [...],
    products: [
        // SwiftGraphQL
        .library(name: "SwiftGraphQL", targets: ["SwiftGraphQL"]),
        .library(name: "SwiftGraphQLClient", targets: ["SwiftGraphQLClient"]),
        .library(name: "SwiftGraphQLCodegen", targets: ["SwiftGraphQLCodegen"]),
        // CLI
        .executable( name: "swift-graphql", targets: ["SwiftGraphQLCLI"]),
    ],
    dependencies: [...],
    targets: [...]
)
```

How can I build a binary executable file for `swift-graphql` using `swift`?

I have already tried `swift build -c release`, but I can't find the binary file that may be executed by the user, and `swift build -c release --show-bin-path`, but the returned path points to the folder containing all packages, not just SwiftGraphQLCLI executable.

Answer (score 0):

I figured you could list all products in the package using `swift package describe`.

Once you find the product name of the package you want to build, you can build it using the following script

```bash
swift build -c release --product <product> --disable-sandbox
```